# Ninject Conditional Binding to Change Scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, scope, ninject

Using Ninject in a MVC4 application with the MVC3 Ninject Extension, when binding to a repository (a DbContext), I want to use `InRequestScope` for Controllers, and InSingletonScope when the same repository is used within a custom `MembershipProvider`.

I want to do this:

```
kernel.Bind<IRepo>().To<Repo>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IRepo>().To<Repo>().WhenInjectedInto<MembershipHelper>()
                               .InSingletonScope();
```

So that each web request to a controller gets a fresh instance of the repo, while the MembershipProvider maintains a re-usable connection to the repo.

This appears to work ok in a development environment, but how do I know which binding is being used? Is there a way to test that the scope is working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. Here's a very easy way to test it:

```
public interface IRepo { }

public class Repo : IRepo { }

public class MembershipHelper
{
    private readonly IRepo _repo;
    public MembershipHelper(IRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public string GetId()
    {
        return _repo.GetHashCode().ToString();
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepo _repo;
    private readonly MembershipHelper _helper;
    public HomeController(IRepo repo, MembershipHelper helper)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _helper = helper;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(_repo.GetHashCode().ToString() + " " + _helper.GetId());
    }
}
```

Now navigate to `/home/index` and observe the 2 hashcodes. The first changes on each request whereas the second remains the same.